# dotnet custom template not renaming lowercase version of sourceName

Tags: templates, .net-core, command-line-interface

I have a custom .NET template that generates an entire solution.  Below is my template JSON config file.

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/InsertNameHere",
    "author": "MiTek Nucleus Team",
    "classifications": [ "ASP.NET", "Nucleus API", "Solution" ],
    "identity": "Nucleus.InsertNameHeres.AspNetCore.WebAPI",
    "name": "MiTek Nucleus Service",
    "sourceName": "InsertNameHere",
    "preferNameDirectory": true,
    "placeholderFilename": "-.-",
    "shortName": "nucleus-service",
    "tags": {
        "language": "C#",
        "type": "solution"
    },
    "sources": [
        {
            "modifiers": [
                {
                    "exclude":[
                        "**/[Bb]in/**",
                        "**/[Oo]bj/**",
                        "**/.git/**",
                        "**/.vscode/**",
                        "**/.vs/**",
                        ".InsertNameHere.config/**/*",
                        "**/*.filelist",
                        "**/*.user",
                        "**/*.lock.json"
                    ],
                    "rename": {
                        "editorconfig": ".editorconfig",
                        "gitignore": ".gitignore",
                        "npmrc": ".npmrc",
                        "gitkeep": ".gitkeep",
                        "helmignore": ".helmignore"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I was under the impression, from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/issues/1746), that if I used the `sourceName` value and put it lowercase that it would it would take whatever is used in `dotnet new <template> -n <some_name>` and make `<some_name>` lower case.  I've got a folder named `insertnamehere` but it never gets replaced.  I also have a TypeScript file, called `insertnamehere-api.module.ts` that doesn't get replaced either.

Is there a way to get the folder name and TypeScript file name to get replaced with the lowercase version of whatever the name of the solution is?

Answer (score 1):

I did a lot more digging and I ended up finding a resource that had the information I needed.  It's located [here](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki).  I had to use the combination of the `symbols` and `forms` sections in order to accomplish what I wanted to do.  I decided to use `Template.1` for the `sourceName` property and `Template.2` for the symbols `fileRename` property.  The value source is dotnet's `name` property so if I want it replaced how it is spelled I use `Template.1` and if I want it lowercase I use `Template.2`.

### Updated template.json configuration file

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/template",
    "author": "MiTek Nucleus Team",
    "classifications": [ "ASP.NET", "Nucleus API", "Solution" ],
    "identity": "Nucleus.Template.1s.AspNetCore.WebAPI",
    "name": "MiTek Nucleus Service",
    "sourceName": "Template.1",
    "preferNameDirectory": true,
    "placeholderFilename": "-.-",
    "shortName": "nucleus-service",
    "tags": {
        "language": "C#",
        "type": "solution"
    },
    "symbols": { // This section is new
        "sourceNameLower": {
            "type": "derived",
            "valueSource": "name",
            "valueTransform": "LowerCaseSourceName",
            "fileRename": "Template.2"
        }
    },
    "forms": { // This section is also new
        "LowerCaseSourceName": {
            "identifier": "lowerCaseInvariant"
        }
    },
    "sources": [
        {
            "modifiers": [
                {
                    "exclude":[
                        "**/[Bb]in/**",
                        "**/[Oo]bj/**",
                        "**/.git/**",
                        "**/.vscode/**",
                        "**/.vs/**",
                        ".Template.1.config/**/*",
                        "**/*.filelist",
                        "**/*.user",
                        "**/*.lock.json"
                    ],
                    "rename": {
                        "editorconfig": ".editorconfig",
                        "gitignore": ".gitignore",
                        "npmrc": ".npmrc",
                        "gitkeep": ".gitkeep",
                        "helmignore": ".helmignore"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```